# Is it ok to add an answer for a later software version?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes I see questions tagged [sql-server-2005](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005), but I have an answer for a later version, like [sql-server-2019](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2019). Things have changed and it works in a slightly different way.

Is it ok to add an answer for that?

[This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/328362/22336) is an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the target version, and clarify it won't work for the requested version.

It may not be what the OP is looking for (at the moment). But it should be useful for the general public, and maybe for the OP later. A useful addition IMO.

Of course, if you know an answer for the requested version that's not already given, add that (in the same answer) first.

(Can't speak to your given example.)